# Updating coordinates on changing model's address using Google-Maps-For-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have noticed with the Google Maps For Rails gems which otherwise works perfectly that when I change an address in the model field the coordinates are not automatically updated, even though the address field is updated and saved. I have created an before_save method that calls geocode.

```
before_save :update_location_coordinates # in model being mapped

protected 

def update_location_coordinates  
    place = Gmaps4rails.geocode(gmaps4rails_address).first  
    self.longitude, self.latitude = place[:lng], place[:lat] unless place.empty?  
rescue  
    nil  
end
```

This works but I am wondering if it is necessary as it seems like something that should be automatic in the gem. Am I missing something?

thanks...

PS geocode returns an array so I just took the first (best) guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The refresh of the coordinates is a tricky process because of the `gmaps4rails_address` method. It's flexible so easy to use but the counterpart is it's not possible to know if the address really changed.

That's why I give coders two different opportunities to fit their needs:

1. If you don't care about performance, you could refresh the coordinates every time the model is saved (and then even if the address hasn't changed). See here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization.

Change `:check_process` to `false`:

```
    acts_as_gmappable :check_process => false
```

2. If you want to have full control over the process, set the `gmaps` boolean to `false` whenever you want the coordinates to be updated. It could be a hidden field in your form or a hook in your model checking the necessary fields.

Comment: great! thanks. Now, I know what that gmaps field is for. I guess I missed it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an economic way to solve the problem:

1. add a column to the model - eg last_g4r_address
2. add a before_validation function:

   def check_g4r_address
       self.gmaps = false if last_g4r_address != gmaps4rails_address
       self.last_g4r_address = gmaps4rails_address
     end

This way the geocoding is updated only if the address changed.

Comment: Even more economic here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/208